# My chat message is deleted if it's identical to a previously deleted message

Tags: bug, chat

When in chat if I type something and then I delete it, and if I then type the exact same thing and send it right after I sent the one that I deleted, it disappears.

Why is this so? Is this a bug? Or by design?

Comment: There is actually a mechanism of deleting duplicate consequent messages, and it looks like it simply doesn't take into account that the previous message could be removed.  So in this case, it seems to be a bug.

Comment: It used to show error message, the auto-client-side-delete is new behavior, like @nic said most likely a simple oversight.